# Sign document with certificate from Windows Certificate Store via Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

I am searching for the best way how to implement a PDF document signature to my web application. I need to sign documents with a certificate stored on a USB token (TokenME device). The certificate is accessible via Windows Certificate Manager (or Windows Certificate Store) when the USB token is plugged in. The application is a web application written in Django and Google Chrome is the supported browser.

Is there some JavaScript library that can be easily used without the necessity to install any additional client on the user's system? I have found several Chrome extensions (e.g. [signingExtensions](https://signingextension.nextsense.com/#!packages)), but they require a desktop application to work and installing an external client may not be acceptable for my client.

Another possibility is to develop a custom desktop client (in .NET or Python). The client would be connected to my application and would provide signature service using the Certificate Store. This would be acceptable for the customer as they would have access to the source code of the client.

However, is there any way how to use only the services provided by Google Chrome browser?